# How to integrate SAP with web application

Tags: polymer, abap

how to integrate the SAP application to the web application which developed in polymer.

Answer (score 2):

A common way that web applications integrate with SAP is using REST or SOAP webservices. Some of your options may depend on the version of the SAP Netweaver Application Server that you have.

You can create REST webservices using SAP Gateway which was incorporated in to the core of the Netweaver Application Server in version 7.4. Here is an overview of that https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/24/a-simple-overview-on-sap-netweaver-gateway/

You can find more details on SOAP webservices from this wiki page https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/ABAP+Connectivity++-+Web+Services+ABAP.